# Twig Templating If statement (Unexpected tag name error)

Tags: templating

Sorry if this is a really obvious question, I'm new to Twig and Craft. I'm getting the following error: 
Unexpected tag name "offset" (expecting closing tag for the "if" tag defined near line 54)

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
<div class="box alt container">
{% set offset = true %}
{% if offset %}
<section class="feature left">
    {% set caseHero = entry.heroImage.first() %}
    <a href="#" class="image icon fa-signal"><img src='{{caseHero.url}}' alt="" /></a>
    <div class="content">
        <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{entry.description}}</p>
    </div>
</section>
    {% offset = false %}
{% else %}
<section class="feature left">
    {% set caseHero = entry.heroImage.first() %}
    <a href="#" class="image icon fa-signal"><img src='{{caseHero.url}}' alt="" /></a>
    <div class="content">
        <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{entry.description}}</p>
    </div>
</section>
    {% offset = true %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to set offset to false after your first section.

To do this correctly you would need to use set like this:

```
{% set offset = false %}
```

[Checkout the documentation to set a variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem line is this one:

```
{% offset = true %}
```

It needs to be:

```
{% set offset = true %}
```

I think there are a couple of occurrences.

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised that the answer above says the same thing. Mark his as the correct answer if you agree.

Comment: Thanks, yes there were two occurrences thank you